# Print string with a php variable in it

Tags: php, html

For you guys, I imagine this will be easy.

```
<div class="vote_pct" style="width: $widthpx;">
```

I want the variable to be $width and for it to have px on the end.
If i put a space, it doesnt work.
If i put them together, it treats it as one big variable name.

Could I ask someone the correct snytax to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mix PHP and HTML you can do:

```
//PHP in HTML
<div class="vote_pct" style="width: <?php echo $width; ?>px;">

HTML in PHP
print '<div class="vote_pct" style="width: ' . $width . 'px;">';
```

Comment: Oh dear, I totally forgot to echo it. 
What am i doing?
Awful error to make.
Sillyness!
Cheers bud

Answer (score 2):

- `$bla = '<div class="vote_pct" style="width: '.$width.'px;">';`

or

- `$bla = "<div class=\"vote_pct\" style=\"width: ${width}px;\">";`

Comment: :) or: $bla = "<div class='vote_pct' style='width: $width px;'>";

Comment: @galambalazs: you need to escape variables if you inserting them to a string.

Comment: @fabrik no you don't. Double quotes allow that. Check before you argue... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<div class="vote_pct" style="width: '.$width.'px;">';
```

or

```
$width = 5;

echo "<div class=\"vote_pct\" style=\"width: {$width}px;\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo sprintf('<div class="%s" style="width: %spx">','vote_pct',$width);?>
```

Comment: changed, im sure he would of found that out anyways :)

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Comment: Separating the literal string `vote_pct` as a parameter of `sprintf()` is just weird and unnecessary.  The literal string should be simply written in the first parameter. This unexplained answer is not teaching best practices.