# Parse error: syntax error T_variable or T_string

Tags: php

We have the following code

```
<?php
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$sum= $num1 * 1.59;
echo "The final price is ". $sum;
?>
```

and we would like it to show the final price is £9.99 for example , but wherever we try to add the £ into the sum it just seems to throw out errors usually either  PHP Parse error:  syntax error T_variable or T_string ive tried £ . $sum; - . £$sum; but nothing seems to work

Appreciate any help

Dan

Comment: This question Needs Debugging Details because we do not know exactly what `$num1` is and we don't know the exact error message.  It is also potentially a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178980/print-string-with-a-php-variable-in-it

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried: `echo "The final price is £". $sum`?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to format the output of the number so its decimal is only two digits long. It is normally a good idea to parse your input to make sure it is what you think it is (i.e. make sure the POST var 'num1' is actually a number).

```
<?php
$sum= number_format((floatval($_POST['num1']) * 1.59), 2);
echo "The final price is £". $sum;
?>
```

Some documentation links for ya:

floatval - http://php.net/floatval

number_format - http://php.net/number_format

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `echo sprintf("The final price is £%01.2f");` ?

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 0):

try This

$sum= number_format((floatval($_POST['num1']) * 1.59), 2);

Answer (score 0):

```
We have used money format and that your according currency code in your choice
```

Your more info please [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)