# Why isn't my image un-caching?

Tags: php, caching, cache-control, image-caching

I need an image to constantly be updated when the page is reloaded so I decided to put a number at the end of the path but for some reason my code keeps breaking the page:

```
<?php $t = getDate(); ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/logo-apptivation.jpg?t=<?php .$t ?>"/>
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: `<?php .$t ?>` should be `<?php echo $t; ?>`

Comment: @crypticツ Thanks, this seems to produce the following URL (notice the word Array at the end): http://path/logo.jpg?t=Array

Comment: You should post it as answer before someone steals it :P

Comment: Oh right, I'll change that a bit then.

Comment: @Maxorq this question is being marked for closing as it is too localized.

Comment: Duplicate of many; including: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178980/print-string-with-a-php-variable-in-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/logo-apptivation.jpg?t=<?php echo time(); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php printf('%s/img/logo-apptivation.jpg?%s', 
                             bloginfo('template_url'),time());?>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the word Array appear at the end of my URL

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Could/Should be: `printf('<img src="%s/img/logo-apptivation.jpg?%s"/>', bloginfo('template_url'), time());`  And an explanation would be good too.